# AWS Sagemaker notebook instance not updating to latest changes in repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

My understanding is that if I stop and then restart the Sagemaker notebook instance, that the most recent changes in the connected git repo should show up in the notebook. However, that is not happening. I pushed changes to the repo, then I stopped and restarted the notebook and it still had the old changes. Is there an extra step required to get the changes from the repo into the notebook instance?

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a terminal and pull the changes using git and resolve any conflicts. Once that is done, the notebook will have the changes from the repo. Stopping and restarting the notebook does not automatically load the recent changes in the connected repo.